# How to do wordwrap for chart labels using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to implement the horizontal bar chart using d3.js.Some of the chart labels are too long.
How to do word wrap for the chart labels on y aixs?

Source code:

```
var data = [{"Name": "Label 1", "Count": "428275" }, { "Name": "Label 2", "Count": "365005" }, { "Name": "Label 3", "Count": "327619" }];

var m = [30, 10, 10, 310],
w = 1000 - m[1] - m[3],
h = 550 - m[0] - m[2];

var format = d3.format(",.0f");

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w + 10]),
    y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, h], .4);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickSize(h),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(0);

$("#chartrendering").empty();
var svg = d3.select("#chartrendering").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
    .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

// Set the scale domain.

x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.Count; })]);
y.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.Name; }));

var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(0," + y(d.Name) + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", function (d) { return x(d.Count); })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

bar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "value")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.Count); })
    .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("dx", +55)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function (d) { return format(d.Count); });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.It is working fine in the Chrome.But the foreignObject elemement is not supported in IE.
Is there a way to handle this object?

Comment: You could position a `div` on top of your graph at just the right position, but apart from that you would have to break the lines manually.

Comment: I have tried the foreignObject element in this way:

svg.selectAll('g.y.axis g').append("foreignObject")
                .attr({ width: 250, height: 45 })
                .attr("x", -250)
                .attr("y",-5)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .append("xhtml:div")
                .style({
                    width: '250px',
                    height: '45px',
                    "font-size": "12px"
                })
        .html("Sales representative");
Can you please explain or give an example using "div" element on top of the graph ?

Comment: The idea is that you place a `div` with fixed positioning completely separate from the actual graph. That is, first you create the graph and then you add `div`s for the labels that are not part of the SVG, thus avoid having to use `foreignObject`.

Comment: See this answer here. Works without foreignObject.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24904941/1299991

Answer (score 10):

Here is a working implementation I've written by pulling together various bits. As the other answer suggests, foreignObject is still the way to go. First the function:

```
var insertLinebreaks = function (t, d, width) {
    var el = d3.select(t);
    var p = d3.select(t.parentNode);
    p.append("foreignObject")
        .attr('x', -width/2)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", 200)
      .append("xhtml:p")
        .attr('style','word-wrap: break-word; text-align:center;')
        .html(d);    

    el.remove();

};
```

This takes in a text element (t), the text content (d), and the width to wrap to. It then gets the parentNode of the `text` object, and attaches a `foreignObject` node to it into which an `xhtml:p` is added. The `foreignObject` is set to the desired `width` and offset `-width/2` to center. Finally, the original text element is deleted.

This can then be applied to your axis elements as follows:

```
d3.select('#xaxis')
    .selectAll('text')
        .each(function(d,i){ insertLinebreaks(this, d, x1.rangeBand()*2 ); });
```

Here I've used rangeBand to get the width (with *2 for 2 bars on the graph).

[image: Resulting image with wrapped labels]

Comment: Beware that this is not supported by IE9 :(

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for solutions to this problem, and found that Mike Bostock has published a [working example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) using D3. The example is shown to work for the x-axis, but can easily be adapted for the y-axis.

Comment: @artfulrobot How to make that example work for nv.addGraph() in nvd3 bar chart?

Comment: You'll need to ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function I wrote not only to solve the y-axis word wrap problem, but also wrap word that is more than 1 line in length, and also align the corresponding 'tick' in the center of the label:

Result is like this:
[image]

See this snippet:

```js
var tempArray2 = [{date: "2017/3/11", ratio: 1}, {date: "2017/3/12", ratio: 0.5}, {date: "2017/3/13", ratio: 0.3}, {date: "2017/3/14", ratio: 0}, {date: "2017/3/15", ratio: 0.8}];

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 80
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
barHeight = 40;
labelWidth = 0;

tempArray2.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
})

dateRange = Math.round((new Date(tempArray2[tempArray2.length - 1].date) - new Date(tempArray2[0].date)) / 1000 / 3600 / 24);

svg = d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("style", "width: 500px\; height: 300px\;");

var x = d3.scaleUtc().range([0, width])
  .domain([toUTCDate(tempArray2[0].date), calculateDays(toUTCDate(tempArray2[tempArray2.length - 1].date), 1)]);

var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1)
  .domain(["Domain for testinginginging", "Another domain used for testing", "Horizontal bar"]);

passBar = svg.selectAll(".passBar")
  .data(tempArray2)
  .enter();

passBar.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "passBar")
  .attr("height", barHeight)
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(calculateDays(toUTCDate(d.date), d.ratio)) - x(toUTCDate(d.date));
  })
  .attr("y", y("Horizontal bar") + (y.bandwidth() - barHeight) / 2)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + (margin.left + x(toUTCDate(d.date))) + ", 0)";
  });

failBar = svg.selectAll(".failBar")
  .data(tempArray2)
  .enter();

failBar.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "failBar")
  .attr("height", barHeight)
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(calculateDays(toUTCDate(d.date), 1 - d.ratio)) - x(toUTCDate(d.date));
  })
  .attr("y", y("Horizontal bar") + (y.bandwidth() - barHeight) / 2)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + (margin.left + x(toUTCDate(d.date)) + x(calculateDays(toUTCDate(d.date), d.ratio)) - x(toUTCDate(d.date))) + ", 0)";
  });

//add grid lines
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")")
  .call(make_x_gridlines(dateRange)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickFormat("")
  )

// always draw axis at last
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")")
  .attr("class", "xAxis")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(dateRange).tickFormat(d3.utcFormat("%m-%d")))
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", 0)")
  .attr("class", "yAxis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("class", "cateName")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .call(wrapText, margin.left - 13);

function calculateDays(date, number) {
  date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + number);
  return date;
}

function make_x_gridlines(tickTime) {
  return d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(tickTime);
}

function toUTCDate(input) {
  var tempDate = new Date(input);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(tempDate.getFullYear(), tempDate.getMonth(), tempDate.getDate()));
}



function wrapText(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      textContent = text.text(),
      tempWord = addBreakSpace(textContent).split(/\s+/),
      x = text.attr('x'),
      y = text.attr('y'),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy') || 0),
      tspan = text.text(null).append('tspan').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).attr('dy', dy + 'em');
    for (var i = 0; i < tempWord.length; i++) {
      tempWord[i] = calHyphen(tempWord[i]);
    }
    textContent = tempWord.join(" ");
    var words = textContent.split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      spanContent,
      breakChars = ['/', '&', '-'];
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(' '));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        spanContent = line.join(' ');
        breakChars.forEach(char => {
          // Remove spaces trailing breakChars that were added above
          spanContent = spanContent.replace(char + ' ', char);
        });
        tspan.text(spanContent);
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append('tspan').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).attr('dy', lineHeight+'em').text(word);
      }
    }
    var emToPxRatio = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(text._groups[0][0]).fontSize.slice(0, -2));
    text.attr("transform", "translate(-" + (margin.left - 13) + ", -" + lineHeight + ")");

    function calHyphen(word) {
      tspan.text(word);
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        var chars = word.split('');
        var asword = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
          asword += chars[i];
          tspan.text(asword);
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            if (chars[i - 1] !== "-") {
              word = word.slice(0, i - 1) + "- " + calHyphen(word.slice(i - 1));
            }
            i = chars.length;
          }
        }
      }
      return word;
    }
  });

  function addBreakSpace(inputString) {
    var breakChars = ['/', '&', '-']
    breakChars.forEach(char => {
      // Add a space after each break char for the function to use to determine line breaks
      inputString = inputString.replace(char, char + ' ');
    });
    return inputString;
  }
}
```

```css
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: center;
}
.passBar {
    fill: #a6f3a6;
}
.failBar {
    fill: #f8cbcb;
}
.grid line {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
.xAxis {
    font-size: 15px;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.yAxis {
    font-size: 15px;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Main function about word wrap is this one: `wrapText`.
Modified from
https://bl.ocks.org/ericsoco/647db6ebadd4f4756cae
and
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do automatic word wrap in SVG. You could use `foreignObject` and HTML `div`s for that purpose, but that would require modifying the code that creates the axis labels. Alternatively, you can rotate the axis labels so that they have more space. See for example [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html) for how to do that.

Comment: Here is an example of using foreignObject for word wrap: http://tributary.io/inlet/5320723

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to plumb Mike Bostock's `chart()` function into [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/).  For background, see https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/36.

```
        discretebar: {
            dispatch: {
                renderEnd: function(e){
                    d3.selectAll(".tick text").call(wrap,_chart.xAxis.rangeBand());
                }
            }
        },
        callback: function(chart){
            _chart = chart; //global var
        }
    }
```